# Sitecore custom MTA for localhost

Tags: email, sitecore, sitecore8.1

I am trying to figure out EXM for Sitecore. I installed it and now I am trying to configure it to send emails from my local machine. SAC MTA is not an option because I don't have access to App Center. I am left with custom MTA.

I was trying to configure config files to use gmail smtp:

Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.config

```
    <smtpSettings type="Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.SmtpSettings, Sitecore.EDS.Core" singleInstance="true">
      <server>smtp.gmail.com</server>
      <port>465</port>
      <userName>*****@gmail.com</userName>
      <password>*****</password>
      <authenticationMethod>Login</authenticationMethod>
      <startTls>true</startTls>
      <proxySettings ref="exm/eds/proxySettings" />
    </smtpSettings>
```

Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.Sync.config

```
   <pop3Settings>
      <pop3Setting type="Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Pop3.Pop3Settings, Sitecore.EDS.Core" singleInstance="true">
        <server>pop.gmail.com</server>
        <port>995</port>
        <userName>****@gmail.com</userName>
        <password>****</password>
        <useSsl>true</useSsl>
        <startTls>true</startTls>
        <proxySettings ref="exm/eds/proxySettings"/>
      </pop3Setting>
    </pop3Settings>
```

But when I try to "send quick test" through EXM I get "Failed to connect to the email server. Please try again later". Can anyone help me with that configuration. And is it even possible? I remember reading something about paid license to use custom MTA. Would it mean, that you need to pay to send email via EXM?

Answer (score 1):

To switch from using the Sitecore MTA to using the Custom SMTP, you must disable the Dyn configurations and then enable the CustomSmtp configurations:

- In the Website\App_Config\Include\EmailExperience folder, add the suffix .disabled to the end of the following file names:

  - Sitecore.EDS.Providers.Dyn.config
  - Sitecore.EDS.Providers.Dyn.Sync.config
- In the  Website\App_Config\Include\EmailExperience folder, remove the suffix .disabled from the following file names:

  - Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.config.disabled
  - Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.Sync.config.disabled

Comment: You basically quote the instruction. And I did all of that but it was not sending any mail. That is why I was trying to configure CustomSmtp configs.